# Trouble deploying function using serverless and MoonMail

Tags: serverless-framework, moonmail

I'm trying to deploy a serverless function, however I cannot achieve it.

```
sls function deploy getBeeTokenProxy
Serverless: Deploying the specified functions in "dev" to the following regions: us-east-1
Serverless: - events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Cannot find module 'nodent' from 'C:\dev\testproject\_meta\_tmp\getBeeTokenProxy@1491336313096\node_modules\ajv\lib'
    at C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:46:31
    at processDirs (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:177:39)
    at ondir (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:192:13)
    at load (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:77:43)
    at onex (C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:100:31)
    at C:\dev\testproject\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:23:47
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
```

> serverless -v
>   0.5.6
>
> node -v v7.8.0

Any idea? Maybe I'm using the wrong version of Serverless. I have `ajv@^4.9.1` under `node_modules`.

Comment: Hi! You should be using serverless v0.5, although it seems that in this case the issue is caused by a missing module. Have you tried doing a `npm i nodent` inside `api/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm install nodent --save
npm install js-beautify --save
```

I put --save here because these librairies are not in the package.json of MoonMail.